# processing: how to display text on a 3d object

Tags: geometry, processing

I am new to processing, currently I want to display a 3D ball and also add a text label to the 3D ball.
I am using the code as below:

```java
// this function is called when this sketch is first loaded
void setup()
{
  // choose size (width, height) of your sketch
  size(720, 546, P3D);

  // Choose background color for your sketch
  background(0);
}

    // This function is called repeatedly to draw stuff on screen.
void draw()
{
  lights();
  pushMatrix();
  translate(500, height*0.35, 0);
  fill(236,112,20);
  noStroke();
  sphere(40);
  popMatrix();

  //fill(255);
 fill(255,112,20);
 textAlign(CENTER);
 textSize(15);
 stroke(10);
 text("hihihihi", 500, height*0.35);
    }
```

It turned out that the text "hihihihi" is covered by the ball, but when I do it with 2D object it displays good. Is there anything wrong here, can anyone tell me what might be the problem of my code?Thanks!

Comment: Are you using OpenGL? It willl help if you could post your minimised but functioning program so that people would know about stroke(), text() and post suggestions about the problem. Thanks

Comment: I am using P3D, the setup() is like this: 
// this function is called when this sketch is first loaded
void setup()
{
  // choose size (width, height) of your sketch
  size(720, 546, P3D);
   
  // Choose background color for your sketch
  background(0);
   
  // Load the font file
  //font = loadFont("AndaleMono-36.vlw");
}

Comment: I am sorry. :) I did notice your tag of 'processing' below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that your sphere has a radius of 40 which is means a diameter of 80 and you're drawing both the text and sphere at the same horizontal position(500).

Move the text to the right to avoid the sphere occluding it:

```
void setup()
{
  size(720, 546, P3D);
  background(0);
}
void draw()
{
  lights();
  pushMatrix();
    translate(500, height*0.35, 0);
    fill(236, 112, 20);
    noStroke();
    sphere(40);
  popMatrix();

  fill(255, 112, 20);
  textAlign(CENTER);
  textSize(15);
  stroke(10);
  text("hihihihi", 585, height*0.35);//make sure the text isn't occluded by anything else(like a sphere) 
}
```

If you want to render text on a sphere I recommend trying [PShape](http://processing.org/reference/PShape.html) and [PGraphics](http://processing.org/reference/PGraphics.html).
Here's a minimal example:

```
PShape sphere;
void setup()
{
  size(720, 546, P3D);
  background(0);

  PGraphics sphereTexture = createGraphics(40,40);
  sphereTexture.beginDraw();
  sphereTexture.background(236, 112, 20);
  sphereTexture.fill(255);
  sphereTexture.text("Hi",20,20);
  sphereTexture.endDraw();

  sphere = createShape(SPHERE, 40);
  sphere.disableStyle();
  noStroke();
  sphere.setTexture(sphereTexture); 
}
void draw()
{
  lights();
  pushMatrix();
  translate(500, height*0.35, 0);
  fill(236, 112, 20);
  noStroke();
  shape(sphere,0,0);
  popMatrix();

  fill(255, 112, 20);
  textAlign(CENTER);
  textSize(15);
  stroke(10);
  text("hihihihi", 585, height*0.35);//make sure the text isn't occluded by anything else(like a sphere) 
}
```